# Insert Trigger not firing when creating record by REST API

Tags: apex, trigger, rest, insert

I Have (after insert, after update) trigger on Account sObject. When I manually inserting or updating Account trigger fires, also when I updating existing Account via REST API request it fires too. But when I creating new Account via REST API using INSERT or UPSERT methods trigger is bypassed.
Even if trigger contians just one line:  System.debug ('trigger fired')

Can't find any relevant info that can help to determine the problem. Maybe there is some restriction or settings to allow firing after insert by REST API?

Comment: This shouldn't be possible, triggers will be fired regardless of the way the DML (insert update delete undelete) is happening.

Comment: I've been having this exact same issue. From everything I see, the trigger is set up properly and my inser/upsert on the triggered record is working properly, just the trigger isn't firing. I have a "sendEmailTrigger on EmailMessage (after insert)" instantiation that works when adding a new EmailMessage to a case through the web portal, but when adding the record via REST API the trigger is never fired. I wonder what could cause this, it's really been impeding the progress on my development.

Comment: @PJC It's actually possible.  I'd have to check with my Admin about which App it is (could be DBAmp or another, I can't remember), but there is a setting on there that essentially tells triggers to not fire.

Comment: Can we see the trigger code?  Might be a simple order of operation issue.

Comment: @dphil DBAmp has its own specific settings that control whether certain actions are triggered or not. I agree with Pieterjan Carly: triggers are always fired, depending of course on whether an object reaches that stage in the order of execution.
user13281: stupid question, but is the trigger Active?

Comment: Do any one find solution to the above problem.. I am facing the same issue.